Every $f\in C_c^0$ is analytic?! Where is the mistake in the proof?
Let $f\in C_c^0(\mathbb{R})$ (continuous with compact support) and denote by $\rho_a$ the Gaussian density with standard deviation a and mean 0 (i.e. $\rho_a(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a^2}} \exp({-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{a^2}}) $.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous due to its compact support, we find $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x-y) - f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|y|<\delta$. With this choice of $\delta$ we can choose $a$ small enough such that $\int_{B_\delta(0)^c} \rho_a(x)dx=1-\text{erf}(\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}a}) < \varepsilon$.
Now for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$
|f\ast \rho_a (x) - f(x)| 
\leq \int_\mathbb{R} \rho_a(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)|dy
=\int_{B_\delta(0)} \rho_a(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)| dy
+\int_{B_\delta(0)^c} \rho_a(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)|dy
\leq \varepsilon \int_{B_\delta(0)} \rho_a(y)
+2 \vert\vert f \vert\vert_\infty \int_{B_\delta(0)^c} \rho_a(y) dy
\leq \varepsilon + \vert\vert f \vert\vert_\infty \varepsilon =(1+\vert\vert f \vert\vert_\infty)\varepsilon
$
which shows that $f \ast \rho_a$ converges uniformly to $f$.
But since $\rho_a$ is analytic, we know that $f \ast \rho_a$ is also analytic for every $a>0$, and therefore, the uniform limit $f$ would be also analytic.
This is obviously not true in general.
Where does the proof go wrong? I can't find a mistake by myself.

The uniform limit of analytic functions on an open domain of the complex plane is analytic. Here the convergence holds in $\mathbb{R}$

Let me add that  the only continuous function with compact support which is analytic is the zero function.

Okay, so that was the mistake. Thanks a lot.
